# Js check if pair exists in array of pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like so:

```js
const arr = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 7]]
```

Say I have two numbers: `3` and `4`, how do I check if a pair of those two numbers (regardless of it's order exists in the array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get the `index` of the pair or `-1` if not found:

```js
const arr = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 7]];

const searchForPairInList = (a, b) =>
  arr.findIndex(([first, second]) => 
    (first === a && second === b) || (first === b && second === a)
  );

console.log( '3, 4:', searchForPairInList(3, 4) );
console.log( '7, 5:', searchForPairInList(7, 5) );
console.log( '3, 3:', searchForPairInList(3, 3) );
```

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: The following method **only works when the two numbers are unique**, i.e when `a !== b`

This can be done with a `for` loop and the built in `Array.includes()`, which returns a Boolean if the specified value is present in the array

```js
const arr = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 7], [3, 4]];

function hasPair(array, a, b) {
    let pairStatus = false;
    for(let pair of arr) {
        if (pair.includes(a) && pair.includes(b)) {
            pairStatus = true;
        }
    }
    return pairStatus;
}

console.log(hasPair(arr, 1, 4)); // false
console.log(hasPair(arr, 3, 4)); // true
```

If you want to find how many instances of the pair exist in the array, you can just replace the `pairStatus` variable with a counter to increment

```js
const arr = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 7], [3, 4]];

function instancesOfPair(array, a, b) {
    let instances = 0;
    for(let pair of arr) {
        if (pair.includes(a) && pair.includes(b)) {
            instances++;
        }
    }
    return instances;
}

console.log(instancesOfPair(arr, 3, 4)); // 2
```

Comment: `hasPair(arr, 3, 3)` -> true

Comment: @georg Thanks for pointing that out, I've corrected my answer